# Calling open() with 'append' mode throws: [Errno 2] No such file or directory exception in Python

Tags: python, file, io

It is kind of weard situation and I can not find similar problem anywhere. In my situation we call 'open' with 'append' parameter, as below.

I am using a function that calls other mehod:

```
fileManager.saveNewLine(result_line, results_path, "a")

#below is fileManager
def saveNewLine(text, path, mode):
    hs = open(path, mode) #<-- throws: [Errno 2] No such file or directory...
    hs.write(text + "\n")
    hs.close()
```

And the file `path` is:

> 'ml_models/signals/results/model-training-1h-Core-hourly-True-True-True-0.2-1-9-500-32-1-0.2-1-5-lstm-relu-linear-5000-300-10-10-250-250-6000-14-13000-col--MlModel-time-2023-01-14_23-12-24.301759.txt'

The path (relative) has only **198** characters. The folder **ml_models/signals/results** exists. I ran out of ideas what else can be wrong.

As far as I know 'append' should create new file if exists. Tested also with `w` parameter.

> "a" - Append - Opens a file for appending, creates the file if it does
> not exist.
>
> "w" - Write - Opens a file for writing, creates the file if
> it does not exist

Comment: Just updated question, same problem with `w` parameter. Ill try shortly with shorter file name and see result...

Comment: First question: is the path correct?
Please, write your code (with the path) and the folder tree of your project

Comment: As I wrote in body of my my question, `ml_models/signals/results` exists, so it is correct.

Comment: In that case, it is necessary to have you project folder tree and the proper code

Answer (score 1):

It appears, that it was an issue with path length. For path below it is fine:

> 'ml_models/signals/results/something-time-2023-01-14_23-12-24.301759.txt'

My conclusion is that for file system counts absolute not relative file path.